# Experiments stuck on VALIDATING ibmq_16_melbourne

Tags: ibm-q-experience

Since yesterday I'm trying to run on the new composer ([quantum-computing.ibm.com](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com)) both new experiments (never run before) and older experiments (that have been successfully run and completed some ago) on `ibmq_16_melbourne`, but they're stuck on `VALIDATING` and never run.

I can successfully run experiments on other devices `ibmqx4`, `ibmqx2` and `ibmq_qasm_simulator`.

Issue is only with `ibmq_16_melbourne`.

Does this depend on my account or on the device itself?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this only on the Circuit Composer? Have you tried with the Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: @JamesWootton thank you. Circuit Composer only. I tried now with Jupyter notebooks and the job runs.

Comment: Close for No-repro. Not helpful for future users.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, it was broken but now it's fixed!